# form data not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried to link my form to a php file but there was an error and data was not submitted. I dont understand how to fix it. help me fix it

Form code:

```
        <form  target="_blank" action="details.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">Male
                        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female"> Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ask question and provide background information</td>
                    <td><textarea name="information" rows="5" cols="20">put your question and background information here</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

php file code:

```
<?php if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'reset' ){
            $_POST['firstName'] = "";
            $_POST['lastName'] = "";
            $_POST['Email'] = "";
            $_POST['phoneNumber'] = "";
            $_POST['Gender'] = "Male";
            }
    ?>
```

rest of the code is same as form but instead of text box and radio there is php coding

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [fix it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Isjgc0oX0s).

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: Please use print_r($_POST) to see if the data is being posted to the other page. Let me know if it contains data.

Comment: whats your problem
Change `<input type="reset" name="submitForm" value="reset">` instead of `<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="reset">` To reset form

Comment: why you used input type="submit" for reset button?use type="reset" for your reset button then try.

Comment: Rob : still same error.
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Reload this webpage.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Answer (score 2):

Change `value="submit"` to `value="reset"`

```
 <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit">
```

If below code is not on `details.php`

```
<?php 
       if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'reset' ){
            $_POST['firstName'] = "";
            $_POST['lastName'] = "";
            $_POST['Email'] = "";
            $_POST['phoneNumber'] = "";
            $_POST['Gender'] = "Male";
       }
    ?>
```

Then also consider to remove `target="_blank"` from the `form` tag

**Edit**

According to your Updated question, you have two submit buttons in HTML change one to `type="reset"`, and also add [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset) function to the `if` condition

```
if(isset($_POST['submitForm']) && $_POST['submitForm'] == 'reset' )



  <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitForm"
                value="submit"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Remove this one `<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit">` and it will work

See live [Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rvh-k8c)

Comment: What is the `error` ?

Comment: Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Reload this webpage.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: See updated answer and the demo here http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rvh-k8c

Comment: thanks a lot, its working. but what if I want to place the php in a separate file and then try to run the form?

Comment: Glade that it helped you. Just add `target="_blank"` and in `action="yourPage.php"` in the form tag and copy the PHP code to `yourPage.php`
Consider to accept this answer

Comment: last time I did that and thats when the problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reset the form you can use button type reset and not submit.

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: even if I set it as reset, nothing happens still error: data not received.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **target="_blank"** from form tag.

if you want to post form data to another page please set form action tag

```
<form  action="page url" action="details.php" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit">

<?php if($_POST['submitForm'] == 'submit' ){
        $_POST['firstName'] = "";
        $_POST['lastName'] = "";
        $_POST['Email'] = "";
        $_POST['phoneNumber'] = "";
        $_POST['Gender'] = "Male";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">Male
                        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female"> Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="35"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="20"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ask question and provide background information</td>
                    <td><textarea name="information" rows="5" cols="20">put your question and background information here</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="submit"><input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="reset"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitForm']))
{
            $_POST['firstName'] = $fname;
            $_POST['lastName'] = $lname;
            $_POST['Email'] = $email;
            $_POST['phoneNumber'] = $phonenumber;
            $_POST['Gender'] = $gender;
            // your query goes here......
}

?>
```